# Set different texts for text view in dynamically added textview XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

My question is how to set different texts for a text view added dynamically from a xml,

Sample Code:

```
ViewGroup view = (ViewGroup) findViewById(android.R.id.content);

LinearLayout r = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.test11);

LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)this.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
for(int i =0 ; i<20 ; i++) {
   r.addView(layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mcdonald_card, view, false));
    }
```

R.layout.mcdonald_card:

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">


<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test222"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Info"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aaaaaaaaa" />

    </LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

how can i change test222's text so the 20 added have different texts? 
and if that is not possible what are the alternatives ? 
thank you in advanced

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
for(int i =0 ; i<20 ; i++) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mcdonald_card, view, false);
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.test222)).setText("some text");
    r.addView(view);
}
```

**UPDATE**
Modify your xml to include the button, something like this.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="@dimen/card_margin">

    <LinearLayout
        style="@style/Widget.CardContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/test222"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Info"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="aaaaaaaaa" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

and your code should look like

```
for(int i =0 ; i<20 ; i++) {
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.mcdonald_card, view, false);
    ((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.test222)).setText("some text");
    ((Button)view.findViewById(R.id.button)).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                //Do whatever you want here on click of button
            }
        });
    r.addView(view);
}
```

Comment: thats working :D 
what if i want to add a buttonin the xm,,,, and set a listener for each button